# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable in python

Tags: python, mysql

```
def export_csv_standard_units(name):
    cursor.execute("select distinct(standard_units) from activities where standard_type='IC50' ")
    result_standard_units_distinct = cursor.fetchall()

    cursor.execute("select standard_units from activities where standard_type='IC50' ")
    result_standard_units = cursor.fetchall()

    field_standard_units = ()
    cnt = []

    for result in result_standard_units_distinct:
        field_standard_units = field_standard_units + (result_standard_units_distinct,)

    length = int(len(field_standard_units))

    for i in result_standard_units:
        for j in length:
            if field_standard_units(j) == result_standard_units(9):
                cnt[j] = cnt[j] + 1
    field = (field_standard_units, cnt)

    export_field = open('%s_standard_units.csv' %name, 'wb')
    export_csv_field = csv.writer(export_field)
    export_csv_field.writerows([field])

    export_field.close()
```

I have some problem to run my python file.
I want to make the csv.file for data counting
like this..

standard_units   count
standard_unit1   123
standard_unit2   234

but, It has error like this.

```
   File "manage.py", line 42
     for j in length:
   TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

What does it mean iterable?

Comment: Something like Array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like your error message said: `int`s are not iterable. Use a [`range`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range)

```
for j in range(length):
    ...
```

If `length` is 10, `range(length)` will give you the values 0..9.

You don't have to actually calculate the length in advance - instead you can [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) the `field_standard_units`:

```
for j, unit in enumerate(field_standard_units):
    if unit == result_standard_units(9):  # What's 9?
        ...
```

Note:
Use [`xrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) if your range is very large since `range` creates a list, and thus all of its members occupy the memory, whilst `xrange` creates a generator just like `enumerate`.