# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable in python (newbie)

Tags: python

I am an newbie in python, while running this code it gives me this error "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" in line 14. Please let me know my mistake.

```
x=int(raw_input())
y=int(raw_input())
z=int(raw_input())
n=int(raw_input())
xarr = [ i for i in range(x+1) ]
yarr = [ j for j in range(y+1) ]
zarr = [ k for k in range(z+1) ]
results = []
for i in xarr:
    for j in yarr:
        for k in zarr:
            results.append([i,j,k]) 
for w in range(len(results)+1):
    if (sum(w) != n):
        results=results.append(sum(w))
print results
```

if x=1, y=1, z=1 and n=2 then 
results = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
and I am checking sum of each index of the list results and if the (sum==n) then do not add that index in results list

So output should be : 
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Like the error says, `w` is an integer, and you can't call `sum()`  on an integer; what would it sum? It's not clear what you're trying to do, though; you should state what you expect the result to be.

Comment: So what is your expected output? The indices of the triples that sum to `n`? That'd be `[0, 1, 2, 4, 7]` for your sample.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28450126/typeerror-int-object-is-not-iterable-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You are summing an integer:

```
for w in range(len(results)+1):
    if (sum(w) != n):
```

`w` is an integer from the `range(len(resultss)+1)`. If you wanted to sum the triples you produced in `results`, just loop directly over the results:

```
for w in results:
    if (sum(w) != n):
```

although it is not clear to me why you are looping over the length *plus one*. Python indices are 0-based, the last index is at `len(results) - 1`, not `len(results)`.

You are making it harder on yourself than is needed. Python has several easier options you are missing here.

- `list.append()` returns `None`. You are replacing `results` with `None` here:

  ```
  results = results.append(sum(w))
  ```

  Remove the `results =` part altogether.

  And are you **certain** you want to combine the `(x, y, z)` triplets with the `sum()` results in *one list*?
- When using a list comprehension that does nothing but loop and copy the elements to a list (`[i for i in iterable]`), just use `list()` on the iterable:

  ```
  xarr = list(range(x + 1))
  ```

  Since all you do is iterate, you don't actually have to do this *at all*. And there is rarely a need to convert `range()` objects to lists, you can address individual indices directly without doing so. Just use your `range()` objects directly:

  ```
  xarr = range(x + 1)
  ```
- You can use the [`itertools.product()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to produce your results:

  ```
  from itertools import product

  results = product(range(x + 1), range(y + 1), range(z + 1))
  ```

  Again, no need to convert this to a list since you are going to iterate over this.
- If you wanted to add *indices* of the triplets, use `enumerate()` to produce those together with the triples so you can test the sum, then add the index to a result list:

  ```
  indices = []
  for i, w in enumerate(results):
      if (sum(w) != n):
          indices.append(i)
  ```

You can put everything into a one-liner after this, using a list comprehension:

```
from itertools import product

x = int(raw_input())
y = int(raw_input())
z = int(raw_input())
n = int(raw_input())

indices = [i for i, w in enumerate(product(range(x + 1), range(y + 1), range(z + 1)))
           if sum(w) != n]
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use range here

```
"range(len(results)+1)"
```

As results will be a list of list [[x,y,z], [x,y,z]].

Try this:

```
for w in results:
    if (sum(w) != n):
        results=results.append(sum(w))
```

Or do like this:

```
for w in range(len(results)+1):
    if (sum(results[w]) != n):
```

Comment: There are some other major problems in that code. `results=results.append()` will lead to a `AttributeError: NoneType has no attribute 'append'`, for example.